# Fixar icone no canto direito inferior usando Materialize

Tags: html, css, html5, materialize

Primeira vez que estou usando o **materialize**.

Gostaria de saber como fixar um icone no canto inferior direito.

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-large cyan pulse right"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
```

De forma nativa se houver.

Comment: Qual versão do Materialize?

Comment: @hugocsl É versão 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não achei uma classe nativa para fazer isso na documentação, mas vc pode fazer um ajuste usando um `top` de 100% menos a altura do próprio btn.

Veja como fica no exemplo abaixo:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.btn-bottom {
    top: calc(100% - 56px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn-floating btn-large cyan pulse right btn-bottom"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
```